# Instantiate a provider in TestBed with the instance of another provider

Tags: unit-testing, angular, testing

How do you instantiate a provider in `TestBed.configureTestingModule()` with an instance of another provider?

An example (doesn't work obviously):

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      { provide: ServiceOne, useValue: new ServiceOne('parameterOne')},
      { provide: ServiceTwo, useValue: new ServiceTwo(TestBed.get(ServiceOne), 'parameterTwo')}
    ]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [factory provider](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#factory-provider)

```
providers: [
  { provide: ServiceOne, useValue: new ServiceOne('parameterOne')},
  { 
    provide: ServiceTwo, 
    deps: [ ServiceOne ],
    useFactory: (serviceOne: ServiceOne) => {
      return new ServiceTwo(serviceOne, 'parameterTwo')
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.